# Why I obtain a white page when I import a backup of an old WP blog on my local web server?

Tags: installation, wp-config, localhost, configuration, local-installation

I am pretty new with WP (I came from Joomla) and I am finding some problem loading an old WP backup on my local Apache.

I have take the directory containint an old blog (named blog) and I have put it inside my local **www** directory of my Ubuntu local system.

Then I have import the database backup on my local MySql server and finally I have change the **wp-config.php** file changing the information about my local database.

The problem is that when I try to open the address:

```
http://localhost/blog/
```

in my browser it appear a withe page and I can't see no output

Why? What could be the problem? How can I try to solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Enable [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) mode and see if any errors are being generated. There are a lot of details that can go wrong with site migration so it's tricky to just guess.

Comment: do you mean have this line in the wp-config.php file: define('WP_DEBUG', true); ? If yes I have it enamble but I see nothing !!!

Comment: Are there any errors in web server error log? PHP might be crashing it.

Comment: where can I find these logs? I think that PHP have no problem because other website in other subfolders of www are correctly opened

Comment: That depends on your server (Apache or whatever) setup completely. Something might be happening in that specific site that causes PHP to crash, that happens.

Comment: ok on Ubuntu the log should be /var/log/apache2/error.log but there is nothing important in it related to this WP installation

Comment: Ok no...I see it again the log and I found:

[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12